# Want to extract Text from HTML Document

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to scape some information from [the Kickstarter website](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology?ref=discover_index). The information is structured and every Kickstarter project code looks the same:

```html
<div class="project-card-content">
<h6 class="project-title"><a data-pid="714867756" data-score="null" data-version="null" href="/projects/massoudhassani/mine-kafon-drone?ref=category_recommended" target="">Mine Kafon Drone</a></h6> <p class="project-byline">Massoud Hassani</p>
<p class="project-blurb">
Introducing the Mine Kafon Drone, an airborne demining system  developed to clear all land mines around the world in less than 10 years
</p>
</div>
```

I need the three following strings for every `<div class="project-card-content">`. For example:

1. Mine Kafon Drone
2. Massoud Hassani
3. Introducing the Mine Kafon Drone, an airborne demining system  developed to clear all land mines around the world in less than 10 years

For the first result I used this code code in Python:

```
import urllib
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    theurl = "https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?category_id=16&woe_id=23424829&sort=popularity&seed=2448324&page=1"
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

    project1 = soup.find('div', {'class': 'project-card-content'}).findChildren('a')
    print (project1)
```

The result is:

```
[<a data-pid="714867756" data-score="null" data-version="null" href="/projects/massoudhassani/mine-kafon-drone?ref=category_recommended" target="">Mine Kafon Drone</a>]
```

But I only want the string `"Mine Kafon Drone"`

Answer (score 1):

Simply get text from the first "a" tag you've found.

```
text = project1[0].text
print(text)
```

Result would be:

```
Mine Kafon Drone
```

To get data from every :

```
data = []
for div in soup.find('div', class_='project-card-content'):
    data.append(div.find('div', class_='project-title').text)
```

Comment: oh yes... that works. And how can I get a list with all the data from the website in this html-field? like: "Mine Kafon Drone" and "Petcube Bites + Petcube Play: Treat & Care for Pets Remotely" "Voices of Humanity - The World's Space Time Capsule". If I add the _all to soup.find I get an error. THANKS

Comment: @SebastianFischer what do you mean by "a list with all the data"?

Comment: I need all the data of this class. On the website [link](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology?ref=discover_index) you can see that every project has a class="project-title". actually python only shows the first "project-title". I need a list with all titles. Bit when I use soup.find_all it doesn't work.

Comment: @SebastianFischer I've updated my answer, check it out :)

Comment: Thank you so much. But I get an error: "TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments" Do you knwo why?